# Is A closed? Open?

Tags: general-topology

can you help me prove or refute this affirmations?
Let $ A = \left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R^*}\times \mathbb{R}  : \frac{y}{\sqrt{\left | x \right |}}\leqslant 1 \right \} 
 $

i) A is a closed set of $ \mathbb{R^2} $

ii) A is an open set of $ \mathbb{R^2} $

I claim both are false. To prove A is not a closed set, let ($x_n,y_n$)  $ A\ni \left ( \frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n+1} \right ) \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}\left ( 0,0 \right )\notin A $

To prove A is not open, let (xn, yn) = $ \left ( 1, 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right ) \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}\left ( 1,1 \right )\in A $, however $ \left ( 1, 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right ) \notin A  $, $ y = 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} > 1$

Is this right? P.S. For some reason my indexing doesn't work. :(

Comment: For me your proof looks fine. Why do you say that the indexing doesn't work?

Comment: I tried to use \index{} command, but it doesn't work. I meant that I don't know how to properly index xn yn so that it looks pretty.

Comment: You should use underscore. Type x_n to get $x_n$

Comment: Thanks! I will use that in the future!